# PSAD does not start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, security, psad

I complied PSAD from source, compilation went smoothly however when I run this command:

```
sudo psad --sig-update
```

I got this:

```
 Can't load '/usr/lib/psad/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Date/Calc/Calc.so' for module Date::Calc: /usr/lib/psad/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Date/Calc/Calc.so: undefined symbol: DateCalc_Day_of_Week_to_Text_ at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/DynaLoader.pm line 184.
 at /usr/sbin/psad line 3218.
```

Comment: Have you investigated the mismatch between PSAD's Perl requirements and what's present on your Ubuntu? What version of Ubuntu are you running? Have you tried to find a PPA for PSAD instead of doing the tarballing? Have you considered rolling up your own .deb file via `fpm`?

Comment: @Deer Hunter  perl -v  --> This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi and I have ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same phenomenon and fixed it.
It is caused by the lack of required modules of Perl in the system.
Try this;

1. By using `cpan` or [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) (Perl module manager), install [`Date::Calc`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Calc/lib/Date/Calc.pod) like,

   ```
   cpanm Date::Calc
   ```
2. Retry installation by `./install.pl` of PSAD source tree.